# Why has my CSS stopped inside of my polymer autobinding template?

Tags: css, data-binding, polymer

I'm trying to use CSS and the autobinding template with polymer, but I'm running into a few issues.

I have the setup with a `<core-header-panel main mode="waterfall-tall">` inside a `core-drawer-panel`. This has the effect that my header grows and shrinks (gains/loses the `.tall` class) when I scroll.

I'm playing on this to hide and show my link tabs. Have a look:

[image: Expanded]

[image: Collapsed]

What I did have set up, before I implemented the 'autobinding' was a `more-vert` menu item, that only appeared when the `.tall` class was *not* there. I'm using this CSS snippit

```
core-toolbar.tall #morebutton {
  display: none;
}
core-toolbar.tall #morebutton-dropdown {
  display: none;
}
core-toolbar:not(.tall) #tabs {
  display: none;
}
core-dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left: 0;
  }
```

And this html:

```
<body fullbleed layout vertical>
<core-drawer-panel id="drawerPanel">

  <core-header-panel drawer>
    <core-toolbar id="navheader" >
      <span>Menu</span>
    </core-toolbar>
    <core-menu>
      <core-item label="Welcome"><a href="#welcome" target="_self"></a></core-item>
      <core-item label="History"><a href="#history" target="_self"></a></core-item>
      <core-item label="Review"><a href="#reviews" target="_self"></a></core-item>
    </core-menu>
   </core-header-panel>

  <core-header-panel main mode="waterfall-tall">
    <core-toolbar id="mainheader" >
      <paper-icon-button id="navicon" icon="menu" ></paper-icon-button>
      <span flex>Malmesbury Tandoori</span>
      <span flex></span>
    <!-- <template is ="autobinding"> -->
    <div relative flex>
     <paper-icon-button id="morebutton" icon="more-vert"></paper-icon-button>
         <core-dropdown id="morebutton-dropdown" relatedTarget="{{$.morebutton}}">
          <core-menu>
            <core-item>Menu</core-item>
            <core-item>Find Us</core-item>
            <core-item>About</core-item>
          </core-menu>
        </core-dropdown>
      </div>
  <!-- </template> -->
  <paper-tabs id="tabs" class="bottom fit" noink layout scrollable selected="0" flex role="tablist" horizontal center layout>
    <paper-tab role="tab" flex center-center horizontal layout>
      <a href="index.html" class="tab-content">Home</a>
      <paper-ripple id="ink" initialopacity="0.95" opacitydecayvelocity="0.98"></paper-ripple>
    </paper-tab> <paper-tab role="tab" flex center-center horizontal layout>
      <a href="menu.html" class="tab-content">Menu</a>
      <paper-ripple id="ink" initialopacity="0.95" opacitydecayvelocity="0.98"></paper-ripple>
    </paper-tab>
    <paper-tab role="tab" flex center-center horizontal layout>
      <a href="FindUs.html" class="tab-content">Find Us</a>
      <paper-ripple id="ink" initialopacity="0.95" opacitydecayvelocity="0.98"></paper-ripple>
    </paper-tab>
    <paper-tab role="tab" flex center-center horizontal layout>
      <a href="FindUs.html" class="tab-content">About Malmesbury Tandoori</a>
      <paper-ripple id="ink" initialopacity="0.95" opacitydecayvelocity="0.98"></paper-ripple>
    </paper-tab>
  </paper-tabs>

    </core-toolbar>
    <div class="content">
     ......
    </div >
  </core-header-panel>

</core-drawer-panel>
</body>
```

I've commented out the template tag that seems to break it. Without that bit, it looks like so:

[image]

As you can see from the second picture is that my css/html setup is somehow broken by the `autobinding` template.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `<template is="auto-binding">`. In your code you left off the dash.

Personally, I tend to wrap everything inside of `body` in the `auto-binding` template, that way everything gets stamped out at the same time. Otherwise you need to listen for the `template-bound` event to be fired before you can access any of that content with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my tweet Rob!